# Mode over a one year window in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a Redshift table of transactions from members, and associated to each transaction is a state:

```
      date|member_id|transaction_amount|state
----------+---------+------------------+-----
01/05/2012|aaaaaaaaa|             35.50|   WA
02/05/2012|aaaaaaaaa|             35.50|   WA
03/05/2012|aaaaaaaaa|             35.50|   WA
                     ...
01/05/2013|aaaaaaaaa|             35.50|   WA
02/05/2013|aaaaaaaaa|             35.50|   CA
03/05/2013|aaaaaaaaa|             35.50|   CA
                     ...
```

What I would like to do is, for each transaction, pick the state that occurred the most in the previous 12-months, and associate that to the given transaction.

My first thought was to do a join like so:

```
select t0.*, t1.state from transactions t0
join transactions t1
on datediff('month', t1.date, t0.date) between 0 and 12
```

Then I would group by `date`, `member_id`, other columns not shown, `transaction_amount`, and count occurrences of each state, retaining the one that appeared the most (had the greatest `count` in that group).

I've been having trouble doing this last part.  My question is, how do I select the most frequent state from this table for each group?  Another question is, is there a more efficient way to do this (avoiding this join)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a running mode is really tricky.  You can modify your query by doing:

```
select id, state
from (select t.id, t2.state, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by t.id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from transactions t join
           transactions t2
           on datediff('month', t2.date, t.date) between 0 and 12
      group by t1.id, t2.state
     ) ts
where seqnum = 1;
```

This just uses the transaction id.  You might want to test this version where you join back to get the fields that you want and a second version where you include the fields in this query.

(And you might wand to include `member_id` as well; the question is not clear on that point.)

I cannot readily think of a way to do this in Redshift without the self join (or equivalent).